# Hazardous waste packaging

Tags: environmental-engineering, waste-disposal

I'd like to ask an environemental question which has to do with waste packaging and the EU regulations that enclosure this subject

I'd like to package loads of different hazardous wastes in compliance with ADR. So, depending on the waste, I use the labels that are pictured in this link. https://conceptdraw.com/a1276c4/preview

How can I label the packages of some wastes that are not applicable to ADR?

These wastes are:

- brake fluids (16 01 13*)
- antifreeze (16 01 14*)
- synthetic engine, gear and lubricating oils (13 02 06*)

A possible answer is to label them in compliance with the GHS (Globally Harmonized System of Classification and Labelling of Chemicals) which is the regulation for hazardous products but there is no a certain answer if this system is applied for hazardous wastes too.

Comment: Cross post, but no answer as of yet: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/labeling-hazardous-wastes-that-are-not-applicable-to-adr